# How to fix Boolean Difference operator for meshes

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry

I am designing a pair of dice on blender, and instead of the 6 pips on the "6" face, I am placing a 3d mesh of a logo that I have designed (a 3d peacock). I intersect the mesh of the logo slightly with the face, and use the Boolean difference operator to emboss the logo onto the face of the dice:

[image]

Whenever I click on the cube mesh, however, and perform the Boolean difference operation on the 3D mesh of the logo, it does a weird sort of union with the mesh of the logo and the cube face - the feathers on this logo get attached to the face and the whole body is missing:

[image]

How do I fix this issue? (For context, this mesh was created by taking a mesh of a simpler cone looking object, and then performing the Boolean difference operation between collections of that simpler object, separating the difference by connected parts, and then deleting excess. If this affects the geometry and as a result the Boolean operation, please let me know how I can fix that). Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have included the blend file in a google drive link below. I apologize as I am new to blender haha

[image]

Comment: Without the original mesh it's hard to tell, but maybe someone knows better. First of all it looks like the peacock body isn't really connected to the rest, the tail seems to intersect with the body but the ends are open, so it's not a piece of closed geometry. Another thing is, without seeing the mesh of the peacock I cannot judge if there is some messy geometry which makes it harder for the _Boolean Modifier_. Or maybe doubled vertices? Try deleting them by selecting all in _Edit Mode_, then hit M > Merge > By Distance. What you could also try is set _Operand Type_ > "Fast" in the modifier.

Comment: if Gordons answer doesn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: I apologize for not including a blend file earlier - I have included it now! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should not only upload the file and wait for someone to fix it for you... did you try any of my suggestions? Now that I have your file I can say some of the things I mentioned definitely apply here. Your mesh is open in many places, unconnected geometry, merging by distance removes 5627 vertices... then vertices sticking out up and down of the mesh. And in the version you uploaded there's not even a _Boolean Modifier_ on the cube... I'm quite sure it will work  once the mesh is clean.

Comment: I tried applying what you had mentioned (M > Merge > By Distance), but I don't think it fully cleaned up the mesh because I was still running into issues applying the Boolean Modifier on the cube. You had mentioned that the body does not seem to be connected to the tail as some of the ends are open - I think I am noticing this as well. I am looking at the mesh clean up tools but I can't seem to figure out which tools actually resolve this. I am very new to blender so thank you for all your help!